# Multiple Bool to Visibility Converter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm pretty new to WPF. I'm writing small applcation based on Demo from ToggleSwitch avaiable on Codeplex: https://toggleswitch.codeplex.com/

Basically there are 4 Radio buttons bind with 4 xaml files (as it is in the Demo from link I wrote above). Let's called them Base1.xml, Base2.xml etc.

Then I wanted to make the same thing for one of these files.
I put in Base2.xml 3 radio buttons for 3 xamls - Sub1.xml Sub2.xml Sub3.xml. I copied the logic and then I encountered problem.
One of Subx.xml are always visible.

I though that this is visible/collapsed problem and it should be visible/hidden so I tried solution from this link:
http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/

But it doesn't work...

Here's my main xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    [...]
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" x:Name="VLink1" Content="LINK1" Margin="0,0,25,0" IsChecked="True" />
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" x:Name="VLink2" Content="LINK2" Margin="0,0,25,0"/>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" x:Name="VLink3" Content="LINK3" Margin="0,0,25,0"/>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" x:Name="VLink4" Content="LINK4" Margin="0,0,25,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <MyApp:Link1 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Link1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <MyApp:Link2 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Link2, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <MyApp:Link3 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Link3, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <MyApp:Link4 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Link4, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And here's my Link2.xaml:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       [...]
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" x:Name="vSubLink1"     Content="SubLink1"     Margin="25,0,25,0"/>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" x:Name="vSubLink2" Content="SubLink2" Margin="0,0,25,0"/>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" x:Name="vSubLink3"     Content="SubLink3"     Margin="0,0,25,0"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <MyApp:SubLink1 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=vSubLink1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <MyApp:SubLink2 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=vSubLink2, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <MyApp:SubLink3 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=vSubLink3, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Could you please tell me how to solve my problem?

Comment: So, unless you have your radio button bound to a single property, possibly with your own EnumToBooleanConverter or assign the radio buttons to a group with a unique group name for the entire screen, you can have multiple radio buttons checked at once.  Your "IsChecked" needs to be bound to something.

Comment: Please update the code of BoolToVisibilityConverter. Your code seems to be fine and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The element name is wrong in the binding! Try the code changes below and revert if any issues.

```
<MyApp:Link1 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=VLink1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
<MyApp:Link2 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=VLink2, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
<MyApp:Link3 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=VLink3, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
<MyApp:Link4 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=VLink4, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I post as not logged.
@Vishakh Babu - I was renaming my link and I've made a mistake, but this part is and was working OK. I have just problems with my sublinks

Comment: Please update the code of BoolToVisibilityConverter. Your code seems to be fine and it should work as expected

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think I must read more about WPF and maybe more about MVVM. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe there is some other issue with your code. Code is perfect, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me how to solve my problem?

As an aside...you don't necessarily have to use a converter. One could bind directly to a visibility property, either exposed on the view or if you are using MVVM the VM. Such as where I do specific logic on my VM:

```
public Visibility IsSendAvailable
{
    get { return CanSend ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
    set { _IsSendAvailable = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSendAvailable"); }
}
```

Then bind in your Xaml such as

```
<MyApp:SubLink1 Visibility="{Binding IsSendAvailable}"/>
```

assuming that the **page's datacontext** is set to a VM or a View with a property `IsSendAvailable`.

---

Note how it used `INotifyPropertyChange` `OnPropertyChanged` method to announce the change to the world. I provide an MVVM overview on my blog:

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)